# Using requireActual isn't requiring the actual version of module, in a Jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a Jest test file like the following:

```
// utils.test.js
let utils = require('./utils')

jest.mock('./utils')

test('print items', () => {
  utils.printItems(['a'])
  expect(utils.getImage).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('a.png')
})

test('get image', () => {
  utils = require.requireActual('./utils')

  // `utils` is still mocked here for some reason.
  expect(utils.getImage('note.png')).toBe('note')
})
```

And a mock like this:

```
// __mocks__/utils.js
const utils = require.requireActual('../utils');

utils.getImage = jest.fn(() => 'abc');

module.exports = utils;
```

Yet as you can see in my comment in the second test, `utils` is still the mocked version rather than the actual version of the module. Why is that? How can I get it to be the actual version, rather than the mocked version?

Comment: `jest.isMockFunction` is helpful for not running a test if the function isn't mocked the way you expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still get the mocked utils module in your second test because you have actually required it inside the manual mock (`__mocks__/utils.js`), which in Jest's cache is still referenced as a mock that should be returned due to `jest.mock()` being at the top most scope.

A way to fix it is either to not use the module in a manual mock, or update your second test to unmock and require a new version of it. For example:

```
test('get image', () => {
  jest.unmock('./utils')
  jest.resetModules()
  const utils = require.requireActual('./utils')

  // `utils` is now the original version of that module
  expect(utils.getImage('note.png')).toBe('note')
})
```

Comment: I added the `jest.unmock('./utils')` line (along with the rest of your code, which I already had), yet it didn't seem to change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Where did you add jest.unmock() ? Can you post the updated test code that you say isn't working well?

Comment: I put it exactly like you did; I put it inside the test, as the first line, right before the requireActual.

Comment: @chiyanc22 @Gary I think you'll need to do `jest.resetModules()` as well after the `jest.unmock()` call!

Comment: @AhmedAbdelrahman - your suggestion solved the issue for me.
```
jest.unmock('./utils');

jest.resetModules();

const utils = require.requireActual('./utils');
```